# Installing libmysqlclient-dev did not produce libmysqlclient_r.so library

Tags: mysql, qt

I installed `mysql-client`, `mysql-workbench`, and `libmysqlclient-dev` using:

```
    sudo apt-get install mysql-client
    sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
    sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

I need both the `libmysqlclient.so` and `libmysqlclient_r.so` libraries to build the MySql plugin in Qt. While the `libmysqlclient.so` library was built and placed in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, I cannot find `libmysqlclient_r.so` anywhere on my system. I ran `locate libmysqlclient_r.so` which returned no results.

How can I get the `libmysqlclient_r.so` library?

Comment: Run `locate libmysqlclient_r.so`

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that I ran `locate libmysqlclient_r.so` which returned no results.

Comment: Edit your post with that, then.

Comment: Run `locate libmysqlclient_r`, whats the output?

Comment: That also returns no results.

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer that worked for me [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/772250/624585). It looks like `libmysqlclient_r` is not included in the `libmysqlclient-dev` package so I made a symbolic link to `libmysqlclient.so` like so:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient_r.so
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify which library to use.. it worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04.

```
MYSQL_LIBS=-lmysqlclient
MYSQL_INCDIR=/usr/include/mysql
MYSQL_LIBDIR=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Config example that I use:

```
./configure -opensource -nomake examples -nomake tests -release -openssl -plugin-sql-mysql -plugin-sql-sqlite -skip qtwebengine MYSQL_INCDIR=/usr/include/mysql MYSQL_LIBDIR=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu MYSQL_LIBS=-lmysqlclient
```

Comment: Welcome to AU. Could you use the editing possibilities to let code appear as such (select the text in edit mode and click on the 'blockquote' or 'Code sample' icon)? That will  make your answer easier to read.

Comment: Hi Marc. Thanks for suggestion. Hopefully it's better now. :)

Comment: @waldmar: Yes, much better. Congratulations.